# How to redirect multiple subdomains to the same running express app

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, saas

I'm building a SaaS app in NodeJS and using the Express framework. The individual members of the website has a url with a custom subdomain to login.

For example, a company called ABC Corp may login at `abc.example.com` and another company called Sony may login at `sony.example.com`

Any idea how I can redirect/route multiple subdomains to the same app instance?

Comment: If you provide some more information it will help to give much better answer for us.

Comment: What more info do you need @AmolMKulkarni? What I need is to point abc.domain.com and xyz.domain.com to the same express app.

Comment: Not just these 2 subdomains though. I need to wild card match subdomains to the same app. That is *.domain.com should show the same app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [express-subdomain](https://npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain/) package. Assuming you have a `routes` folder, containing `abc.js` and `sony.js` files that respectively export login routes for the abc and sony subdomains, you could have the following in `index.js` or whatever file from which your express server is listening.

```
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const abcRoutes = require('./routes/abc');
const sonyRoutes = require('./routes/sony');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// use the subdomain middleware
app.use(subdomain('abc', abcRoutes));
app.use(subdomain('sony', sonyRoutes));

// a simple get route on the top-level domain
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to the Home Page!');
});

// add any other needed routes

module.exports = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Your server will then be live and working as expected
`http://example.com/` --> Welcome to the Home Page!
`http://abc.example.com/login` --> (Your login page for abc)
`http://sony.example.com/login` --> (Your login page for sony)

To tests subdomains locally you need to add them to your `/etc/hosts` file. (it  requires `sudo` permissions)

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      example.com
127.0.0.1      abc.example.com
127.0.0.1      sony.example.com
```

The equivalent for `/etc/hosts` file on windows is at `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc`

For better details on setting up localhost domains locally [check here](https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain#developing-locally)

You can do more with the subdomain package. It accepts wildcards and you can use it to check API keys if you need such a feature.

Checkout the documentation for the `express-subdomain` package at https://npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain

Answer (score -1):

You can actually handle that particular route or a wide range then go for [`Reg Exp`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.routes)  (which allows you to do this `app.get(new RegExp('(your|string)\/here'), function…`) which you want to redirect and then follow the redirecting action something like below code is doing:

```
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'yourpath/page.html'
  //add other headers here...
});
response.end();
```

---

**Update 1** : [as per the comments and other updates]

Then you try to handle all requests with the following app:

```
express()
.use(express.vhost('abc.example.com', require('/path/to/loginApp').app))
.use(express.vhost('sony.example.com', require('/path/to/loginApp').app))
.listen(80)
```

where `/path/to/loginApp` can be absolute paths or relative paths.

I hope this solves your problem.

**Update 2**:

Actually when a request comes in the request event is raised on a HTTP Server. So basically it is handled by express, `express.vhost` is a middle-ware function which raises the request event on another instance of a HTTP Server, that is how it works.

Below is the code:

```
function vhost(req, res, next){
    if (!req.headers.host) return next();
    var host = req.headers.host.split(':')[0];
    if (req.subdomains = regexp.exec(host)) {
      req.subdomains = req.subdomains[0].split('.').slice(0, -1);
      server.emit('request', req, res);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
```

Comment: `app.get(new RegExp('(your|string)\/here'), function…) ` is for matching stuff that comes after `domain.com/` (path), right? Not for `*.domain.com`, right?

Comment: Got your problem now.. Please check the updated answer.. Hope you can use `reg exp` for your wide range of domains... Happy exploring :)

Comment: Thanks @Amol. My app is just a 1 page test app. See the code at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6009679/ Where do I add the vhost code here and what will be `/path/to/loginApp` in this case? Can u paste any modification at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: I don't have multiple domains to test and show you proper code, but I am sure you can do something like I had mentioned in update. But if you want to know how it works. I will put some code which itself explains how it redirects.